# FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl Always Returns the Default

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC app and am using Forms auth. When going to a page that requires authentication, meaning there is an [Authorize] attribute on the controller action, it redirects the user to the login page with a return url like `http://localhost/Login?ReturnUrl=/MyAuthorizedUrl`.

This is how my config is setup:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
```

This is how I'm getting the redirect url:

```
var url = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl( model.Email, model.RememberMe );
```

This always returns the default url.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you would like to get "MyAuthorizedUrl" as the result of `FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl`?

You'll need to insert a hidden input field that mirrors `ReturnUrl=/MyAuthorizedUrl`, e.g. `name="ReturnUrl" value="/MyAuthorizedUrl"`.

The reason is that the login page is requested via GET with the `ReturnUrl`, but the POST goes to `/Login` (without any parameters).

Alternatively change the form action attribute to include the `ReturnUrl` parameter.

Answer (score 6):

If your login form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm
(
     "Login", 
     "Account", 
     new { ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] },
     FormMethod.Post
))
```

Replace "Login" with your action name and "Account" with your controller name.